# NodeJS multiple requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to figure this out on my own (just started working with NodeJS) and also with help of Google but was not quite able to find out how to do what I want to do.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
1. Call the Clash of Clans API and get the members from my clan, I can do with the help of the request module (https://github.com/request/request)

2. After loading all the members I would like to call the API once more for each member and get their personal stats, this is where I am struggling. From what I have read and understood I should make use of Promises?

Code so far:

```
var request = require('request');
var members = new Array();

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/%238Y89PVOY',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'authorization': 'Bearer my-auth-code'
    }
};

function memberCallback(error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        var members = JSON.parse(response.body)["memberList"];

        for (var member in members){

            var ClashMember = {
                name : members[member].name,
                role : members[member].role
            };

            members.push(ClashMember);

            console.log("Added member");

        }
    }
}

request(options, memberCallback);

// Code to call the api again for each member and get their personal stats
```

I am using the following:

node v10.15.3, npm v6.4.1, Windows 8 64bit

I guess this is more a JavaScript question than a NodeJS question per say so I will tag both and hope that someone with better knowledge than me can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this problem is to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). These are used in conjunction with a mechanism called [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), which is syntax to make handling Promises easier. I suggest you read the above links to understand how these things work.

Here's your current code rewritten to use Promises.

```
const request = require("request-promise");

async function run() {
  const members = [];

  const options = {
    url: "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/%238Y89PVOY",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      authorization: "Bearer my-auth-code"
    },
    json: true
  };

  const response = await request(options);
  const memberList = response.memberList;

  for (const member of memberList) {
    const ClashMember = {
      name: member.name,
      role: member.role,
    };

    members.push(ClashMember);

    console.log("Added member", member.id);
  }

  console.log(members[0]);
}

run();
```

Now that your code can support promises, you can add a request into each iteration of your for loop, and it will work as expected. Something along the lines of this will do.

```
  for (const member of memberList) {
    const memberInformationOptions = {
      // options for this request
    };
    const memberInformation = await request(memberInformationOptions);

    const ClashMember = {
      name: member.name,
      role: member.role,
      extraInformation: memberInformation.body
    };

    members.push(ClashMember);

    console.log("Added member", member.id);
  }
```

This removes your error handling, which you can reimplement using [try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

Answer (score 0):

Let's use promise + async await

Download package from npm request and request-promise.
By async await, you can make your code to look synchronous (but still asynchronous).
Callback method is quite old and your code can be hard to read if you have multiple callbacks.

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out, not sure how to do it though. Could you perhaps provide me with some code example?